# Getting errors using mantine useForm APIs like insertListItem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, use-form, mantine

Hello everyone I am facing some issues regarding using MantineUI. I am trying to crate a form with some nested values.

So, I am trying to use the mantine useForm hook, but when I run the sample code provided in the mantine docs its failing on my machine.

I have attached the error photos as well as code.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
import { useForm } from '@mantine/form';
import { TextInput, Switch, Group, ActionIcon, Box, Text, Button, Code } from '@mantine/core';
import { randomId } from '@mantine/hooks';


function Demo() {
  const form = useForm({
    initialValues: {
      employees: [{ name: '', active: false, key: randomId() }],
    },
  });

  const fields = form.values.employees.map((item, index) => (
    <Group key={item.key} mt="xs">
      <TextInput
        placeholder="John Doe"
        required
        sx={{ flex: 1 }}
        {...form.getInputProps(`employees.${index}.name`)}
      />
      <Switch
        label="Active"
        {...form.getInputProps(`employees.${index}.active`, { type: 'checkbox' })}
      />
      <ActionIcon color="red" onClick={() => form.removeListItem('employees', index)}>
       <Text>Delete</Text>
      </ActionIcon>
    </Group>
  ));

  return (
    <Box sx={{ maxWidth: 500 }} mx="auto">
      {fields.length > 0 ? (
        <Group mb="xs">
          <Text weight={500} size="sm" sx={{ flex: 1 }}>
            Name
          </Text>
          <Text weight={500} size="sm" pr={90}>
            Status
          </Text>
        </Group>
      ) : (
        <Text color="dimmed" align="center">
          No one here...
        </Text>
      )}

      {fields}

      <Group position="center" mt="md">
        <Button
          onClick={() =>
            form.insertListItem('employees', { name: '', active: false, key: randomId() })
          }
        >
          Add employee
        </Button>
      </Group>

      <Text size="sm" weight={500} mt="md">
        Form values:
      </Text>
      <Code block>{JSON.stringify(form.values, null, 2)}</Code>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

[The name "test" should be inside the employee array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQJGg.png)

[and also the insertListItem dosent work even its inside the mantine docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMywi.png)

[Mantine Nested example](https://mantine.dev/form/nested/#nested-arrays)